# Jhipster - i18N - not able to access UI - CRUD generated entity after update json file

Tags: json, jhipster, angular-translate

Actually I'm wondering why by changing my `*.json` files located in `i18N/fr` and `i18N/en`

I'm no longer able to access (CRUD) my generated entity form UI perpective after login.. It keeps spinning but other features works fine.

I want to use the angular-translate feature within my html , actually I just custumized label descriptions located in `*.json` file corresponding in both `i18N/fr` and `i18N/en` 
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

I figure out my issue ! I used TextEdit on MacOS and it keeps adding extra characters in my json files whyle saving them. I switched to sh default editor from command line and it works fine!